# DSE 4.5.1 hadoop node stopped working

Tags: hadoop, datastax

I have 5 node cluster in DSE 4.5 is running and up. out of 5 nodes 1 node is hadoop_enabled. But suddenly Hadoop node stopped working.

Logs :

```
  INFO [JOB-TRACKER-INIT] 2014-08-19 08:18:44,196 CassandraFileSystem.java (line 68) CassandraFileSystem.uri : cfs://54.xx.xx.xx/
  INFO [JOB-TRACKER-INIT] 2014-08-19 08:18:44,196 CassandraFileSystem.java (line 69) Default block size: 67108864
  INFO [JOB-TRACKER-INIT] 2014-08-19 08:18:44,196 CassandraFileSystemThriftStore.java (line 309) Consistency level for reads from cfs: LOCAL_QUORUM
  INFO [JOB-TRACKER-INIT] 2014-08-19 08:18:44,196 CassandraFileSystemThriftStore.java (line 310) Consistency level for writes into cfs: LOCAL_QUORUM
  ERROR [JOB-TRACKER-INIT] 2014-08-19 08:18:44,197 UserGroupInformation.java (line 1124) PriviledgedActionException as:cassandra cause:java.io.IOException: UnavailableException()
  INFO [JOB-TRACKER-INIT] 2014-08-19 08:18:44,197 JobTracker.java (line 2430) problem cleaning system directory: null
  java.io.IOException: UnavailableException()
    at com.datastax.bdp.hadoop.cfs.CassandraFileSystemThriftStore.mutateINode(CassandraFileSystemThriftStore.java:905)
    at com.datastax.bdp.hadoop.cfs.CassandraFileSystemThriftStore.storeINode(CassandraFileSystemThriftStore.java:827)
    at com.datastax.bdp.hadoop.cfs.CassandraFileSystem.mkdir(CassandraFileSystem.java:157)
    at com.datastax.bdp.hadoop.cfs.CassandraFileSystem.mkdirs(CassandraFileSystem.java:140)
    at com.datastax.bdp.hadoop.cfs.CassandraFileSystem.initialize(CassandraFileSystem.java:74)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:1386)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1404)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:254)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:123)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker$3.run(JobTracker.java:2373)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker$3.run(JobTracker.java:2371)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.<init>(JobTracker.java:2371)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.<init>(JobTracker.java:2195)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.<init>(JobTracker.java:2189)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.startTracker(JobTracker.java:303)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.startTracker(JobTracker.java:294)
    at com.datastax.bdp.hadoop.mapred.JobTrackerRunner.initService(JobTrackerRunner.java:84)
    at com.datastax.bdp.hadoop.mapred.JobTrackerRunner.initService(JobTrackerRunner.java:31)
    at com.datastax.bdp.hadoop.mapred.ServiceRunner.run(ServiceRunner.java:127)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
 Caused by: UnavailableException()
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.ThriftConversion.rethrow(ThriftConversion.java:57)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CassandraServer.doInsert(CassandraServer.java:1079)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CassandraServer.doInsert(CassandraServer.java:1061)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CassandraServer.batch_mutate(CassandraServer.java:954)
    at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseServer.batch_mutate(DseServer.java:576)
    at com.datastax.bdp.hadoop.cfs.CassandraFileSystemThriftStore.mutateINode(CassandraFileSystemThriftStore.java:897)
    ... 23 more
```

Can anyone help on this issue? I'm not able to run hive.
Thanks

Comment: Can you post the output of dsetool ring and dsetool listjt

Comment: How was it resolved?